# JavaScript: Cancelling ondragstart asynchronously

Tags: javascript, async-await, drag-and-drop

I have the following code, which doesn't work.

```
    export function makeDraggable(htmlElement: any, dotnetCallbackObject: any): void {
    let onDragStart = async (event: any) => {
        let mayDrag: boolean = await someAsyncFunction('MayDrag');
        if (!mayDrag) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
    htmlElement.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart);
}
```

The browser doesn't seem to wait for the async function to complete, and so immediately enables dragging. I want to be able to determine whether drag should be permitted as a result of an async call. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are synchronous, and need to be, to support bubbling and capturing sanely.

You should eagerly cache the eligibility of dragging and attempt to access that result in your handler instead.

```js
let isDraggable = false
getIsDraggable('maydrag').then((answer) => {
  isDraggable = answer
})
const onDragStart = (event) => {
  if (!isDraggable) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  return isDraggable
}
```